# PHP general form generator/builder

Tags: php, cakephp, webforms, interface-builder, code-generation

I'm looking for an open source php form builder or form generator to add/edit/delete/search records?

I have to create a simple manager for some records, it's a common application that should be found easily, but I can't find any good code/class/application/etc :(

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try CakePHP's [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Scaffolding.html) feature.

Comment: It's a great surprise! This would be greater is it supports `search` and have a better strategy about relationships.
I used it and I should say thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/ is a nice solution that I have used and would recommend.

Comment: It is what I call "Great Form Generator". Looks Clean. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few, assuming you're using a MySql database:

- [PHPGenerator](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/phpgenerator/)
- [phpMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/)
- [PHP MySql Wizard](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/php-mysql-wizard-php-code-generator-for-mysql-.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BenV's list, there's:

[phplens](http://phplens.com/), [phppeanuts](http://www.phppeanuts.org/site/index.php) and [PfP Studio](http://pfp-studio.sourceforge.net/)

HTH

C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php [form builder](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/form-builder.html). It allows to build any kind of web forms

Answer (score 1):

try this one, it's far better then any other mentioned above/below!

http://phpformgen.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

try [php mysql form maker](http://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/php-mysql-form-generator/) , it can help create unlimited number of php forms that you can use for inser, update, navigate, search and delete records from your MySQL database 
[image]